# same script loading multiple times on click event javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $('.settings').click(function(){
    alert();
  });

});
```

I am loading this script on `click` event as I cannot load this on `ready` event. Now when I click on button with class `settings` first time, nothing happens as expected as the script is loaded after I click on button.

Second time, I click on this button, alert is shown one time (as expected).

But the **unexpected behavior** is, when I click for third time, alert is shown 2 times. When I click for 4th time, alert is shown 3 times and so on.

One possible reason that I can think of is, script was loading every time when I click.

What could be the issue? How can I prevent same piece of script from loading again and again?

Thanks!

Comment: every time you click, you add another click handler to `$('.settings')` - perhaps you need the `off` jquery function

Comment: how can I prevent this behavior? how can I add this only once?

Comment: perhaps you need the `off` jquery function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you click, you add a new handler for `.settings`. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.settings', function() {
  alert();
});
```

Comment: note: that will change this behaviour ... *first time, nothing happens **as expected***

Answer (score 2):

This issue will be solved if Click event related to document is fired for only one time when you click first time in settings button.

If you want an event handler to only fire once then take a look at .one(): http://api.jquery.com/one

```
 $(document).one("click",function() {
      $('.settings').click(function(){
        alert();
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Bravo already suggested you need the off handler. You add a click event handler everytime you click. So you should remove the previous click handler before adding another. Something like:

```
$(document).off('click').on('click', (function() {
  $('.settings').off('click').on('click', function(){
    alert();
  });
});
```